# MS Project - how to schedule subtasks

Tags: ms-project, scheduling, tasks

I have organized my plan with Summary Tasks and many, many subtasks. Since it is a little bit difficult to manage every single subtask, I would like to do these operations:

- assign predecessors to Summary Task
- an effort estimation in terms of day (column Work) for every subtask
- assign a resource for every subtask

And in this way have the subtasks automatically schedule with all dates.

As you can see from the image below I have assigned predecessors to summary tasks. The last column is the "Work" Column. The problem is that all the tasks start from 13/10/2016 and so the plan is not correct...

Do you know if there is some option in Project to have a tidy plan?

[image: example]

Comment: You need to Level the plan, which sorts out the over-allocation on each resource, which means that the tasks will be scheduled to start when there is resource free to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Load your predecessor successor logic on your sub tasks.  This will fix the problem.

That said, my practice is to load all the logic on the lowest level task I have in my schedule.  I do not load any logic, predecessor-successor, resources, etc., in the hammock tasks.